# Custom loss function for time series data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to write a custom loss function for the very first time. My model generates a time series data and I want a loss function which would penalize errors later in the series more than the earlier ones. Something like where index of tensor is used to determine the penalty. The tensors have following structure.

y_true
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 48, 1) dtype=float32>

y_pred
<tf.Tensor 'ResNet34/dense_1/BiasAdd:0' shape=(None, 48, 1) dtype=float32>

What should I do to make the penalty a function of index?

```
 def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred) * 'sqrt(tensor_index)'  <- Desired part
   return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)
```

Comment: "Something like where index of tensor is used to determine the penalty" <-- can you explain this?

Comment: Sure, the square of error is computed for each point, with a total of 48 points. First point refers to t=0 where as last point refers to t=47. I want the error at point t=47 to be multiplied by a number to increase the overall error, thus increasing the penalty of errors later in the series. The error at the biggining (t=0) does not concern me much so it can stay as it is. Hope this makes it bit more clear.

Comment: Ok so you just want to index the last element and multiply by some factor?

Comment: Yes, but not just the last element. I want each element to multiply with a factor, and the factor increases as we move towards last element. Fist element lets say has a factor of 1 and and by the time we reach the 48th element, the factor is 5. Just an example. It is pretty easy to to for numpy arrays, not sure how to get it done for tensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try using `tf.linspace`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.random.normal((1, 48, 1))
y_pred = tf.random.normal((1, 48, 1))

def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   penalty = tf.cast(tf.linspace(start = 1, stop = 5, num = y_pred.shape[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
   print(penalty)
   squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred) * tf.expand_dims(penalty, axis=-1)
   return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)

print(custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[1.        1.0851064 1.1702127 1.2553191 1.3404255 1.4255319 1.5106384
 1.5957447 1.6808511 1.7659575 1.8510638 1.9361702 2.0212767 2.106383
 2.1914895 2.2765958 2.3617022 2.4468086 2.531915  2.6170213 2.7021277
 2.787234  2.8723404 2.9574468 3.0425532 3.1276596 3.212766  3.2978723
 3.3829787 3.468085  3.5531914 3.6382978 3.7234042 3.8085105 3.893617
 3.9787233 4.06383   4.1489363 4.2340426 4.319149  4.4042554 4.489362
 4.574468  4.6595745 4.744681  4.8297873 4.9148936 5.       ], shape=(48,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[1.3424503e+00 1.7936407e+00 9.5141016e-02 4.1933870e-01 2.9060142e-02
  1.6663458e+00 3.7182972e+00 2.3884547e-01 1.6393075e+00 9.8062935e+00
  1.4726014e+00 6.4087069e-01 1.4197667e+00 2.7730075e-01 2.6717324e+00
  1.2410884e+01 2.8422637e+00 2.2836231e+01 1.9438576e+00 7.2612977e-01
  2.9226139e+00 1.3040878e+01 5.8225789e+00 2.3456068e+00 2.8281093e+00
  4.2308202e+00 2.6682162e+00 4.0025130e-01 3.5946998e-01 8.0574770e-03
  2.7833527e-01 3.8349494e-01 7.1913116e-02 3.0325607e-03 5.8022089e+00
  4.4835452e-02 4.7429881e+00 6.4035267e-01 5.0330186e+00 2.7156603e+00
  1.2085355e-01 3.5016473e-02 7.9860941e-02 3.1455503e+01 5.3314602e+01
  3.8006527e+01 1.1620968e+01 4.1495290e+00]], shape=(1, 48), dtype=float32)
```

**Update 1**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = tf.random.normal((2, 48, 1))
y_pred = tf.random.normal((2, 48, 1))
def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
   penalty = tf.cast(tf.linspace(start = 1, stop = 5, num = tf.shape(y_pred)[1]), dtype=tf.float32)
   penalty = tf.expand_dims(penalty, axis=-1)
   penalty = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(tf.repeat(penalty, repeats=tf.shape(y_pred)[0], axis=1)), axis=-1)
   squared_difference = tf.square(y_true - y_pred) * penalty
   return tf.reduce_mean(squared_difference, axis=-1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am giving it a try. Will get back to you.

Comment: I am getting a lot more warnings and shape of tensor 'penalty' is not what i expect it to be.


"<tf.Tensor 'custom_loss_function/Cast:0' shape=(None,) dtype=float32>"


num = tf.shape(a_in)[1] is not working as it should. I expect 48 here, not None

Comment: Your first answer was correct. Just needed a minor fix.

`````
penalty = tf.cast(tf.linspace(start = 1, stop = 5, num = y_pred.shape[1]), dtype=tf.float32)

Comment: The orignal answer works after the fix. Thanks. I didnt try the updated one. :)